# Meaning of absolute/relative paths in python stack trace

Tags: python

I ran `top_level_script.py` and got an exception with a stack trace like:

```
File "top_level_script.py", line 114, in main
  …
File "top_level_script.py", line 91, in func1
  ...
File "top_level_script.py", line 68, in func2
  **kwargs)
File "/home/max/.../cccc/ffff/mmmm.py", line 69, in some_func
  obj = SomeClass(…)
File "mmm/ttt/bbb/core.py", line 17, in __init__
File "/home/max/.../pppp/pppp.py", line 474, in func
  ...
File "/home/max/.../pppp/pppp.py", line 355, in some_func
  ...
```

Notice that `mmm/ttt/bbb/core.py` has a relative path while the frame above and below it have absolute paths.  Also, there is no print out of line 17, in `__init__`, and the code being called was "old".  I just changed it, but old code was getting called.  Hence the exception.

I still find the Python's import mechanic sometimes confusing.  Can anyone elucidate what's up with `core.py` and what is the significance, if any, of the relative path shown in that frame?

After some tinkering, my hypothesis was that python was somehow calling the `.pyc` (hence no source shown in the line below).  After tinkering with the file (i.e. changing and saving it), I now get:

```
File "top_level_script.py", line 114, in main
  …
File "top_level_script.py", line 91, in func1
  ...
File "top_level_script.py", line 68, in func2
  **kwargs)
File "/home/max/.../cccc/ffff/mmmm.py", line 69, in some_func
  obj = SomeClass(…)
File "/home/max/.../mmm/ttt/bbb/core.py", line 17, in __init__
  ...
File "/home/max/.../pppp/pppp.py", line 474, in func
  ...
File "/home/max/.../pppp/pppp.py", line 355, in some_func
  ...
```

Now, I can't reproduce the effect but I am still curious if anyone knows what may have happened.

Answer (score 1):

In general, Python is being transparent about how it understands the name of the file.

Whenever Python performs an `import`, the environment variable [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) is consulted and that sets the Python variable [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path).

Path components in`sys.path` can be absolute or relative. A common relative path name is `.` (the current working directory).

If while performing the import, the name found in `sys.path` is based on a relative path, then the file name that appears in the stack trace will also be relative. I also think that if a Python program uses a [relative import](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html) then that too appears as a relative file name.